# Is there different ways to create a menu bar?

Tags: python, tkinter

I've come across two different ways to create a **menu bar**:

---

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

menu_bar = tk.Menu() ■
window.config(menu = menu_bar) #2

window.mainloop()
```

---

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Menu

window = tk.Tk()

menu_bar = Menu(window) ■
window.configure(menu = menu_bar)

window.mainloop()
```

---

Question: what's the **difference** between these lines of code? By this I mean, why is the **syntax** different If they do the same? (I've marked the referred lines of code as ■). How importing *Menu* from tkinter affect the lines of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the difference between these lines of code?

It does the same thing(except the imports. With `from tkinter import Menu`, you are specifically just importing `Menu` and nothing else from `tkinter`. But in the first example, you are importing whole `tkinter` and you can refer to `tkinter.Menu` as `tk.Menu`. But in the second example, you just have to say `Menu`.

Note that in the second example you can still use `tk.Menu` as well as `Menu`. So the second import is rendered useless, and can be removed. It is better to follow the first example.

---

As mentioned by AST, if you say `Menu()`, an existing instance of `Tk()` will be passed as the master argument implicitly. But if you say `Menu(win)`, you are passing `win` explicitly. It is always recommended to pass the `parent` argument explicitly while you work with multiple windows so as to not cause confusions.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the purpose of *window.config(menu = menu_bar)* If we have already assigned *menu_bar* to *window*

Comment: @Nameless We have just made a menu bar. We actually did not say that this menu should be the menu of the `win` window. I might think it is because, at some point we can change the menu if we wanted.